# is there a way to save data from a textfield into a variable so I can save the data to my database

Tags: flutter

I have a textfield and description on my app that id like the data that's input into it to be saved to my database but I cant seem to figure out how to grab that data from the text field and save. is this possible in flutterflow.

Ive tried writing my own custom command for saving to database but the only way I think of doing it is using a parameter on the method but im not sure how to add that data into the method arguments

Answer (score 0):

`TextField` has [`onSubmitted`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onSubmitted.html) callback that's called when the user has finished editing the text. It also has `onChanged` callback when the user changes the text.

If you want finer control, you can pass a [`TextEditingController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) to the `TextField`'s `controller` property.